# PHP xpath contains class and does not contain class

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath, xpathquery

The title sums it up. I'm trying to query an HTML file for all div tags that contain the class `result` and does not contain the class `grid`.

```
<div class="result grid">skip this div</div>
<div class="result">grab this one</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried very much, only //div[contains(@class, 'result') and not contains(@class, 'grid')] and //div[contains(@class, 'result')][not contains(@class, 'grid')] but it was very apparent that my syntax was off right at the get go

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('test.html');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodeList = $xpath->query(
    "//div[contains(@class, 'result') and not(contains(@class, 'grid'))]");

foreach ($nodeList as $node) {
  echo $node->nodeName . "\n";
}
```

Comment: This would also match anything with class = "*result" i.e. "someResult". So you gotta concat spaces to it.

Comment: thanks for the comment crush, that is extremely helpful. as for the solution I'm certain this will work so I'll be giving credit once I'm at a computer and have verified the code. one last question: as a relatively new programmer, where should I be going for my solutions? I feel that asking questions on SO is lazy and that google provides messy resources. any advice? thanks again guys

Comment: Following @crush 's comment, I think the correct way is `//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' result ')]`, or `//div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' result ')]`.

Answer (score 13):

Your XPath would be `//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' result ') and not(contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' grid '))]`

Answer (score 8):

The XPATH syntax would be...

```
//div[not(contains(@class, 'grid'))]
```