# DOMXPath multiple contain selectors not working

Tags: dom, xpath, domxpath

I have the following XPath query that a kind user on SO helped me with:

```
$xpath->query(".//*[not(self::textarea or self::select or self::input) and contains(., '{{{')]/text()") as $node)
```

Its purpose is to replace certain placeholders with a value, and correctly catches occurences such as the below that should not be replaced:

```
<textarea id="testtextarea" name="testtextarea">{{{variable:test}}}</textarea>
```

And replaces correctly occurrences like this:

```
<div>{{{variable:test}}}</div>
```

Now I want to exclude elements that are of type `<div>` that contain the class name `note-editable` in that query, e.g., `<div class="note-editable mayhaveanotherclasstoo">`, in addition to textareas, selects or inputs.

I have tried:

```
$xpath->query(".//*[not(self::textarea or self::select or self::input) and not(contains(@class, 'note-editable')) and contains(., '{{{')]/text()") as $node)
```

and:

```
$xpath->query(".//*[not(self::textarea or self::select or self::input or contains(@class, 'note-editable')) and contains(., '{{{')]/text()") as $node)
```

I have followed the advice on some questions similar to this: [PHP xpath contains class and does not contain class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324179/php-xpath-contains-class-and-does-not-contain-class), and I do not get PHP errors, but the `note-editable` `<div>` tags are still having their placeholders replaced.

Any idea what's wrong with my attempted queries?

**EDIT**

Minimum reproducible DOM sample:

```
<div class="note-editing-area">
    <textarea class="note-codable"></textarea>
    <div class="note-editable panel-body" contenteditable="true" style="height: 350px;">{{{variable:system_url}}</div>
</div>
```

Code that does the replacement:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query(".//*[not(self::textarea or self::select or self::input or self::div[contains(@class,'note-editable')]) and contains(., '{{{')]/text()") as $node) {
    $node->nodeValue = preg_replace_callback('~{{{([^:]+):([^}]+)}}}~', function($m) use ($placeholders) {
        return $placeholders[$m[1]][$m[2]] ?? '';
    },
    $node->nodeValue);
}
$html = $dom->saveHTML();
echo html_entity_decode($html);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this below xpath.

```
.//*[not(self::textarea or self::select or self::input or self::div[contains(@class,'note-editable')]) and contains(., '{{{')]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. My question is updated with a minimum reproducible DOM fragment as well as my code that does the replacement. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I figured out why it is not working -- the <div> element is created via JS after the page is rendered. Without that requirement, your answer works. Therefore accepting as correct.